# Accessing GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in a kubernetes operator

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow

I am adding a task to an airflow dag as follows:

```
examples_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id='examples_generation',
    dag=dag,
    namespace='test',
    image='test_amazon_image',
    name='pipe-labelled-examples-generation-tf-record-operator',
    env={
        'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS': Variable.get('google_cloud_credentials')
    },
    arguments=[
        "--assets_path", Variable.get('assets_path'),
        "--folder_source", Variable.get('folder_source'),
        "--folder_destination", Variable.get('folder_destination'),
        "--gcs_folder_destination", Variable.get('gcs_folder_destination'),
        "--aws_region", Variable.get('aws_region'),
        "--s3_endpoint", Variable.get('s3_endpoint')
    ],
    get_logs=True)
```

I thought I could paste the service account json file as a variable and call it but this doesn't work and airflow/google documentation isn't clear. How do you do this?

Comment: Did  you try to use the Airflow connexion on the UI and then to add the connexion name in the operator?

Comment: I hadn't tried that as this was a python CLI independent of airflow that I want to use kubernetes Pod operator to run independently. I'll look into that.

Comment: In addition, your config can't work because the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable need to reference a file, and not directly the content of the file.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.

Comment: Any ideas on the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions to port the json into an argument

```
examples_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id='examples_generation',
    dag=dag,
    namespace='test',
    image='test_amazon_image',
    name='pipe-labelled-examples-generation-tf-record-operator',
    arguments=[
        "--folder_source", Variable.get('folder_source'),
        "--folder_destination", Variable.get('folder_destination'),
        "--gcs_folder_destination", Variable.get('gcs_folder_destination'),
        "--aws_region", Variable.get('aws_region'),
        "--s3_endpoint", Variable.get('s3_endpoint')
        "--gcs_credentials", Variable.get('google_cloud_credentials')

    ],
    get_logs=True)
```

then in the cli set

```
import json
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json.loads(gcs_credentials))
client = storage.Client(project='project_id', credentials=credentials)
```